# i want to set source of Image Control in xaml(wp8) to a selected image by a chooser task. Unable to do so

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```C#
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
    {  return; }
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(e.OriginalFileName);
    }
}
```

At this point filePath will have something like c:\Data\Users\Public\Picture\Camera Roll\WP_223232.jpg
I want to set this path as the image source of an image control.

I am aware how to do it for a single image by simply using

```C#
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.setsource(e.chosenPhoto);
```

But I have a list of selected/chosen images which I want to display in ListBox as thumbnail. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select multiple photos using PhotoChooserTask. You can achieve that using [MultiPhotoChooser](https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/).

Otherwise, you can write your own code to load all your images and make the user to select from it.